# How do I combine lists of identical lengths into one?

Tags: r, list

Assuming I have two lists:

```
 xx <- as.list(1:3)
 yy <- as.list(LETTERS[1:3])
```

How do I combine the two such that each element of the new list is a list of the corresponding elements of each component list. So if I combined the two above, I should get:

```
> combined_list
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "a"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "b"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 3

[[3]][[2]]
[1] "c"
```

If you can suggest a solution, I'd like to scale this to 3 or more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick. Nicely, `mapply()` will take an arbitrary number of lists as arguments.

```
xx <- as.list(1:3)
yy <- as.list(LETTERS[1:3])
zz <- rnorm(3)

mapply(list, xx, yy, zz, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```